# How To Fetch the value Section wise in UItableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.2

I am trying to  make an app in which i use the Grouped Table view .In that I am creating the sections in which the first letter comes from an array and it is doing perfectly.
the code is below

```
sections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<[PdfNames count]; i++)
{

 NSString *s=[[PdfNames objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];        

    NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"letter like '%@'",s];

    NSArray *check=[sections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];


    if([check count]<1)

    {
         dict=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dict setValue:s forKey:@"letter"];
        [sections addObject:dict];

    }


}
```

But now i am not able to get that hoe can i get the names of pdf from array which belongs to their secion Or starts with that alphabet.

Comment: Can you please tell me what kind of problem you are facing? Now I am getting confuse from your question title and description.

Comment: I have an array Pdf Names now what i have done is i have created a dictionary in which i need the first letter so that it could be used as section header,and the problem is that i am not able to insert the Pdf name from the array in that particular section :)

Comment: Is it one question or two different ? (1) Not able to set letters latter as header. Or (2) Not able to set particular data in table section's row. ??

Comment: I am notable to set the data for that section

Comment: So I hope you are getting my logic as I have stated in my answer. Or you want something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array `sections` which is of course empty. You then create an array `check` based on `sections`. It will therefore also be empty. `[check count]` will always be zero. No `NSDictionary` is going to be created.

Clear?

Answer (score -2):

Try following code its basic logic, I hope you can understand.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
       return 10;  // Number of rows in section.
    } else if (section == 1) {
       return 5;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;   // Let say we have two section.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // Assign your data
    } else if (section == 1) {
       // Assign your data
    }
}
```

Similarly you can check for the `table section` on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: It appears this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Mundi : From title "How To Fetch the value Section wise in UItableview?" I thought user does not know how to separate arrays as per table section.

Comment: Maybe you are right... Still this would not help. Good try, though.

Comment: I think question title and description are confusing.